# Redirect www to subdomain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain, root

I have a website that moved from root to a sub domain. Now I need to redirect all forms of previous URLs (with or without www) to the new sub domain format.

Example:

```
http://www.website.com/ => http://sub.website.com/  
http://website.com/ => http://sub.website.com/  
http://www.website.com/sample-page/ => http://sub.website.com/sample-page/  
http://website.com/images/1.jpg => http://sub.website.com/images/1.jpg
```

What I found up to now is about redirecting sub domain to root. Can you help me please?

Comment: This topic has literally been covered in thousand places. Also there's examples in the docs. Also, not even sure this is a programming, and not an administration question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```